# Conditional horizontal line through entire plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, line

I have a following code:

```
set autoscale xfix
set terminal qt size 1700, 650
stats "memory.log" prefix "A"
set key left top Left title "\n".sprintf('  Time:  %1.1f  h', A_records/1800.0)."\n".sprintf('   Max:  %d  GB', A_max) font ',11'
plot "memory.log" using (column(0)*2/3600):1 w lp notitle pt -1 lw 1
```

I want to add a line through the whole plot that is only plotted when `A_max` exceeds a constant value. How do I do this? `If` condition is straight forward, but how to plot a constant through the entire plot? (There is no separate data columnt in `memory.log` for this constant).

Comment: What does "a line trough the whole plot" mean? A vertical line at x_max or a horizontal line at some y-value? I assume the latter, correct? What is the value of that constant? Maybe depending on data?

Comment: @theozh The latter, horizontal line at some y-value. The value is 376, not depending on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is are possible solutions.
Some random test data is created and in the example if the maximum y-value is >9 then a horizontal line is plotted with value `myConstant`. Run the script several times and you see whether the horizontal line is plotted or not. Check `help ternary`.

In the example the value `ymax` is extracted during plotting the data, but you can extract `ymax` also via `stats` as you did in your example.

**Script:**

```
### plot conditional horizontal line
reset session

# create some random data
set table $Data
    set samples 11
    plot '+' u 0:(int(rand(0)*11)) w table
unset table

set key noautotitle
set yrange[0:10]
myMax      = 9
myConstant = 5

plot ymax=NaN $Data u 1:($2<ymax ? $2 : ymax=$2) w lp pt 7 lc "red", \
     '+' u 1:(ymax>myMax ? myConstant : NaN) w l lc "blue"
### end of script
```

A shorter version, but with a preceding `stats` command to get the maximum y-value would be the following:

```
stats $Data u 2 nooutput

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red", \
     STATS_max>myMax ? myConstant : NaN w l lc "blue"
```

**Update:**

After some testing and insights from [Values of variables after plotting when defined during plot command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77638172/7295599), I guess you get the probably shortest version (without extra `stats`) if you take the initialization `ymax=NaN` from the first version out of the plot command. And then you don't need to plot the horizontal line via the not so obvious `'+' u 1:(ymax>myMax ? myConstant : NaN)`.

```
ymax=NaN 
plot $Data u 1:($2<ymax ? $2 : ymax=$2) w lp pt 7 lc "red", \
     ymax>myMax ? myConstant : NaN w l lc "blue"
```

**Result:**

ymax=8, line is not plotted.

[image]

ymax=10, line is plotted

[image]

Comment: in your command "plot '+' u 0:(int(rand(0)*11)) w table", what is the significance of '+'?

Comment: @helper it's a `special filename` which generates x-values when plotting functions (or here a constant), check `help special-filenames`. I had to use it because for some strange reason the shorter and "obvious" `plot ymax=NaN $Data u 1:($2<ymax ? $2 : ymax=$2) w lp, ymax>myMax ? myConstant : NaN w l` does not work, because apparently `ymax` is reset to `NaN` after the first plot command. I think about posting a question on this.